# TimeZone.getTimeZone() returns GTC zone given empty string, I need none?

Tags: java, timezone

Need none/false output from TimeZone.getTimeZone() if the input to the function is "" (empty string) but I am getting GMT zone. Please help on how to go about this?

Comment: You cannot/should not change the behavior of `TimeZone` class. So check the input by using `if(timezone.isEmpty()) { }`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, when the timezone `String` is empty you want a `null`. Given a `String str`, you should be able to do something like,

```
TimeZone tz = null;
if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
  tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(str);
}
```

Or (with a [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java))

```
TimeZone tz = (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) ? 
        TimeZone.getTimeZone(str) : null;
```